# Google TV Dish Network DVR style integration

Tags: google-tv

I am looking into integrating MythTV with Google TV; I would like to have the same level of integration found with dish network dvr (ability to set things to record from Google TV and look-up recordings).

Is there any api that can be used for that or this is only something that google - dish can do via their partnership ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API your looking for will be released as part of our next major software release.   Please watch [Getting Your Content on Google TV](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNbKpUqkOso) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I know I should not ask, but what would be the time frame for the next major release ?

Comment: You can ask all you want - I can't imagine anyone who knows telling you.  All I can say is that it's soon enough that we were willing to disclose it at Google I/O.